# Can I use old ram in my New Computer

Tags: memory

Had a CyberpowerPC c-series: AD3U1600W4G11-B ( 4 RAM ). My new Computer is also a cyberpowerPC GUA1400BST series: TED38G1600C11BK ( 8 RAM ). New PC is a dual channel.

Answer (score 3):

From what I've been able to gather from the links below, the two memory modules you mention in your question should be compatible.

```
Common Specifications:
- Type: DDR3 SDRAM
- Capacity: 4GB/8GB
- Pins: 240
- ECC: No
- CL: 11
- Data Rate: 1600MHz
- Voltage: 1.5V
- Bus: PC-12800
```

https://www.comx-computers.co.za/AD3U1600W4G11-B-specifications-109384.htm
http://altaok.ge/computers-and-office/pc-components/memory/8gb-team-ddr3-1600-mhz-ted38g1600c11bk.html?sl=en
https://www.impactcomputers.com/ted38g1600c11bk.html?manufacturer_id=2609

Answer (score 2):

Basically yes... as @dsstorefile points out, these look to be essentially the same type of RAM.

Regarding Single Channel vs Dual Channel, it comes down to motherboard support. If you end up with 3 sticks of RAM, the motherboard may run all of them in Single Channel mode or a mixture of Single/Dual Channel (depending entirely on what it supports).

However, if I am not misreading what you have in the old PC, for better performance (with the new Dual Channel motherboard) I would look into purchasing another AD3U1600W4G11-B 4GB module (they seem to be about $50 used).

That said, the absolute best option would be to just buy a new Dual Channel kit of the TED38G1600C11BK variety (but I understand your budget might not allow this).